# Binary Bomb phase 4 confirmation

Tags: c, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I'm currently working on phase 4 of this binary bomb and I have been wraping my head around this for several hours. Here are my current notes.

phase 4 disassemble

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_4:
=> 0x0000000000401016 <+0>:     sub    $0x18,%rsp //rsp =-24
   0x000000000040101a <+4>:     lea    0xc(%rsp),%rcx // second input = rcx
   0x000000000040101f <+9>:     lea    0x8(%rsp),%rdx // first input = rdx 
   0x0000000000401024 <+14>:    mov    $0x4027cd,%esi // answer format is %d %d
   0x0000000000401029 <+19>:    mov    $0x0,%eax // compare 0 and eax
   0x000000000040102e <+24>:    callq  0x400c30 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x0000000000401033 <+29>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax // compared 2 and eax
   0x0000000000401036 <+32>:    jne    0x401044 <phase_4+46> //if not equal to 2 jump to explode bomb
   0x0000000000401038 <+34>:    mov    0xc(%rsp),%eax // eax = *rsp+12(second input)
   0x000000000040103c <+38>:    sub    $0x2,%eax // subtract 2 from second input
   0x000000000040103f <+41>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax // compare 2 and second input
   0x0000000000401042 <+44>:    jbe    0x401049 <phase_4+51> // if below 2 then jump to +51
   0x0000000000401044 <+46>:    callq  0x401544 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401049 <+51>:    mov    0xc(%rsp),%esi // second input becomes esi
   0x000000000040104d <+55>:    mov    $0x8,%edi // edi becomes 8
   0x0000000000401052 <+60>:    callq  0x400fde <func4> //go to func4
   0x0000000000401057 <+65>:    cmp    0x8(%rsp),%eax // compare first input to eax(from func 4)
   0x000000000040105b <+69>:    je     0x401062 <phase_4+76> //if equal go to 76
   0x000000000040105d <+71>:    callq  0x401544 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401062 <+76>:    add    $0x18,%rsp
   0x0000000000401066 <+80>:    retq
```

func4 disassemble

```
Dump of assembler code for function func4:
   0x0000000000400fde <+0>:     push   %r12 // push r12 onto stack
   0x0000000000400fe0 <+2>:     push   %rbp // push rbp onto stack
   0x0000000000400fe1 <+3>:     push   %rbx // push rbx onto stack
   0x0000000000400fe2 <+4>:     mov    %edi,%ebx // ebx becomes edi(8)
   0x0000000000400fe4 <+6>:     test   %edi,%edi // test 8 & 8
   0x0000000000400fe6 <+8>:     jle    0x40100c <func4+46> //if less than or equal to jump to 46
   0x0000000000400fe8 <+10>:    mov    %esi,%ebp // esi(second input) becomes ebp
   0x0000000000400fea <+12>:    mov    %esi,%eax // esi(second input) becomes eax
   0x0000000000400fec <+14>:    cmp    $0x1,%edi // compare 1 and edi(8)
   0x0000000000400fef <+17>:    je     0x401011 <func4+51> // if equal then jump to 51
   0x0000000000400ff1 <+19>:    lea    -0x1(%rdi),%edi // subtract 1 from edi(8) address
   0x0000000000400ff4 <+22>:    callq  0x400fde <func4> // call function 4
   0x0000000000400ff9 <+27>:    lea    (%rax,%rbp,1),%r12d
   0x0000000000400ffd <+31>:    lea    -0x2(%rbx),%edi // subtract 2 from edi address
   0x0000000000401000 <+34>:    mov    %ebp,%esi // ebp becomes esi(8)
   0x0000000000401002 <+36>:    callq  0x400fde <func4> // call func 4
   0x0000000000401007 <+41>:    add    %r12d,%eax // add r12d and eax
   0x000000000040100a <+44>:    jmp    0x401011 <func4+51> // jump to 51
   0x000000000040100c <+46>:    mov    $0x0,%eax // eax is 0
   0x0000000000401011 <+51>:    pop    %rbx
   0x0000000000401012 <+52>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000401013 <+53>:    pop    %r12
   0x0000000000401015 <+55>:    retq
```

and what I have for notes on how they work together/what the input is suppose to be

the input is "%d %d"

second input has to be 2, i think

goes to line 51

second input becomes ESI(0) after it subtracts 2

EDI becomes 8

goes into func 4

edx becomes EDI(8)

test edi and edi (8 & 8)

I've looked at other similar problems but I am having trouble understanding how people got the answer for their problem. I know there is someone who had basically the same func4 but I didn't quite understand the answer someone gave.

I would like to better figure out what func 4 does. I think, since it starts with a test between edi and edi(both of which are 8) it goes to +46 which makes eax 0, but I don't know where it goes from there.

I am pretty sure that the second input has to be between 2 and 4 but I don't know what the first input does. I am pretty sure that the first goes through func4 and eventually ends up equaling what the first input is.

am I understanding what it does correctly?

thank you very much.

Comment: You have not stated what you want answered or what the problem posed is.

Answer (score 0):

So, looking at `func4`, your comments largely repeat what the instruction does, not what each means...  I suggest working out what the various registers contain at any given moment, and hence what is being done at each step.  Something like this:

```
Dump of assembler code for function func4:
   0x400fde <+0>:     push   %r12
   0x400fe0 <+2>:     push   %rbp
   0x400fe1 <+3>:     push   %rbx

   // Arguments: a in %edi, b in %esi 

   0x400fe2 <+4>:     mov    %edi,%ebx  // %ebx = a (copy of)
   0x400fe4 <+6>:     test   %edi,%edi
   0x400fe6 <+8>:     jle    0x40100c <func4+46> // return 0 if a <= 0

   0x400fe8 <+10>:    mov    %esi,%ebp    // %ebp = b (copy of)
   0x400fea <+12>:    mov    %esi,%eax    // %eax = b (copy of) also
   0x400fec <+14>:    cmp    $0x1,%edi
   0x400fef <+17>:    je     0x401011 <func4+51> // return b if a == 1

   // Have: a in %edi and %ebx -- a > 1; b in %esi and %ebp 

   0x400ff1 <+19>:    lea    -0x1(%rdi),%edi     // argument a for func4: a - 1
                                                 // argument b already in %esi
   0x400ff4 <+22>:    callq  0x400fde <func4>    // func4(a - 1, b)

   0x400ff9 <+27>:    lea    (%rax,%rbp,1),%r12d // r (%r12d) = b + func4(a - 1, b)

   // Have: a in %ebx -- a > 1; b in %ebp ; r = b + func4(a - 1, b) in %r12d

   0x400ffd <+31>:    lea    -0x2(%rbx),%edi     // argument a for func4: a - 2
   0x401000 <+34>:    mov    %ebp,%esi           // argument b for func4: b
   0x401002 <+36>:    callq  0x400fde <func4>    // func4(a - 2, b)

   0x401007 <+41>:    add    %r12d,%eax          // b + func4(a - 1, b) + func4(a - 2, b)
   0x40100a <+44>:    jmp    0x401011 <func4+51> // return result

   0x40100c <+46>:    mov    $0x0,%eax           // return 0

   0x401011 <+51>:    pop    %rbx
   0x401012 <+52>:    pop    %rbp
   0x401013 <+53>:    pop    %r12
   0x401015 <+55>:    retq
```

So it should now be possible to work out what `func4()` is doing, and hence, by similar analysis, what `phase_4` is up to.

Comment: This is helpful, I am still pretty bad at this stuff but I basically copied this into a notepad and changed a to 8 and b to 2 in each occurrence of those variables to see if I can make more sense of this. I wish I was better at this but I'm pretty bad at assembly code. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It takes practice.  It doesn't help that the (so-called) AT&T has arguments in the opposite order to Intel/AMD :-(  Also, when disassembling compiled code, a given variable may be shuffling from one register to another -- particularly around calls.  And then there's the stack-frame and tracking the `%rsp` and/or `%rbp` relative addresses.  What fun !